# Vue and Firebase not sending data

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app that counts the user-visiting number.
I'm using vue.js 3 and firebase.

For now, I'm testing by sending data to firebase. But it has error"firebase.database is not a function"
Can someone help this

```html
import db from './db';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  methods:{

    incrementNum(){
      const numRef = db.database().ref("messages")
      
      numRef.push('hi');
      console.log('sent it')
    },

   
  },
}
```

Comment: How is `db` defined?

Answer (score 1):

The `push()` method returns a promise. Try an `async` method:

```js
import db from './db';

export default {
  name: 'App',

  methods:{
    async incrementNum() {
    // ^^ async
      const numRef = db.database().ref("messages")
      await numRef.push('hi');
      // ^^ await
      console.log('sent it')
    },
  },
}
```